# to generate a loginpage for android using java

Tags: java, android, xml

q1.how to check whether the password and confirm password are same in java?

q2.how to store user datas in xml for loginpage?

Answer (score 3):

> q1.how to check whether the password and confirm password are same in java?

[`equals();`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) ??

> q2.how to store user datas in xml for loginpage?

[Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)